# attaching a hyperlink to results from query

Tags: php, hyperlink

I need to make a website for a hospital as a task in school.
My code is supposed to give me all the consultations that start with the letter that is clicked on, this already works but every consultation should have a hyperlink that leads to the page of that consultation.

This is where I'm stuck. I'm guessing this isn't hard to do, but I'm a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
    <BODY>

        <a href="?searchCons=A">A</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=B">B</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=C">C</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=D">D</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=E">E</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=F">F</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=G">G</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=H">H</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=I">I</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=J">J</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=K">K</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=L">L</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=M">M</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=N">N</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=O">O</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=P">P</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=Q">Q</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=R">R</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=S">S</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=T">T</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=U">U</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=V">V</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=W">W</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=X">X</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=Y">Y</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=Z">Z</a>
        <a href="?searchCons=ALLES">Alles</a>
        <br>

    </BODY>
</HTML>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


include('dbconnect.php');

try {
    if(isset($_GET['searchCons'])) {
        $type  = $_GET['searchCons'];
        if ($type == "ALLES") {
          $query = "SELECT * FROM consultaties";
        foreach ($cn->query($query) as $row) {
            echo $row['Naam']."<BR>"; 
        } 
      }else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM consultaties WHERE Naam LIKE '$type%'";
        foreach ($cn->query($query) as $row) {
            echo $row['Naam']."<BR>"; 
          }
        }
    }
    $cn = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
   die();
}

?>
```

Comment: this data getting from database?

Comment: yes, all the consultations are in the database

Comment: need this? `echo "<a href='?searchCons=".$row['Naam']."'>".$row['Naam']."<BR>";`

Comment: thanks, but every consultation has a different page, and i don't know how to attach the right hyperlink to every consultation

Comment: pages available in this table? `consultaties`

Comment: no, i'll put them in there, thanks for the advice :D

Comment: echo "<a href=".$row['hyperlink']."'>".$row['Naam']."<BR>"; I tried this but it doens't work, do you know why?

Comment: this will work: `echo "<a href='".$row['hyperlink']."'>".$row['Naam']."<BR>";`

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!